# small empty window instead of eclipse and installing a old xulrunner version

Tags: eclipse, xulrunner

When I try to open eclipse, I get a small empty window.

I heard I have to change permissions. I tried that in eclipse and .eclipse, but it didn't work.

I heard I have to install a older xulrunner version.

`apt-get cache search xulrunner` finds xulrunner, but not the older versions

`sudo apt-get install xulrunner=1.9.0.15` doesn't find a xulrunner 1.9.0.15 package to install (I guess it's the ubuntu2 or something that they add by the end, but I use kubuntu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set my workspace to /var/www/projects, but the projects folder wasn't empty, so I made it empty, then run eclipse, then it worked.